# How to pass string variable to javascript function using php

Tags: php

I have a problem about to passing a string parameter to java-script function using PHP. I have an anchor tag as View Live. Here $website contains web URL. On click of link I am opening a popup window. and function to open popup I have a function popup() in javascript. When I click on link I getting error of undefined variable. Can any one help me to solve this problem?

anchor tag is mention in question and javascript function is as follows...

```
function RankPopup(website)
{
        var left = (screen.width/5);
        var top = (screen.height/5);
        newwindow=window.open('abc.php?web='+website,'name',"height=300, width=850,toolbar=no,scrollbars=1,menubar=no,top="+top+",left="+left);
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    }
```

Thank You In advance

Comment: can you post your sourcecode please

Comment: can u pls. post your code over here

Comment: I am afraid Mystic Meg is out of the office today, perhaps you could supply the source code instead

Comment: function RankPopup(website)
{
  var left = (screen.width/5);
  var top = (screen.height/5);
  newwindow=window.open('abc.php?web='+website,'name',"height=300, width=850,toolbar=no,scrollbars=1,menubar=no,top="+top+",left="+left);
  if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
  return false;
 }

Answer (score 1):

The function

This is a function:

```
function example(a,b) {
    number += a;
    alert('You have chosen: ' + b);
}
```

It is called like this:

```
example(1,'house')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just embed the php in the javascript

```
<?PHP $boo = "apples"; ?>
function foo (boo) {
    alert ("input: " + boo);

}

foo ("<?PHP echo $boo; ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have pass php string in javascipt using php tags.see below example.

```
<?php $called="Called javascript function"; ?>

function test(call)
{
    alert(call);
}
test("<?php echo $called; ?>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to pass the value from PHP to Javascript.
I just 
    ?>
    
    var anyname = "";

So, this anyname variable is a javascript global and available for the javascript functions.